# How to add text after every textbox line in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've searched everywhere, I can't find a way.
I want to find a way to add text after every textbox line but I can't find a way to do it.
I have a textbox1 with:

```
example1
example2
example3
And so on...
```

and another textbox2 with @gmail.com

I want the textbox2 to be added to the end of every line in textbox1 like:

```
example1@gmail.com
example2@gmail.com
example3@gmail.com
And so on...
```

Any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try looping through the Lines collection?

Comment: I'm a bit noob in vb.net, i dont know... I just need it to complete a task for me instead of me doing it myself. Please don't judge... I'm really desperate...

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works.  We can help, but you have to meet us halfway.  Post your attempted code.

Comment: I undestand buddy but I really can't seem to work around it... Thanks for your honest answer but I think i will give up i really cant do it alone.. thanks once more...

Answer (score 1):

This solution is concise, and removes empty lines.

```
Private Function appendTextToOtherTextLines(textToAppend As String, otherText As String) As String
    Return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, otherText.
                       Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
                       Select(Function(s) s & textToAppend))
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox3.Text = appendTextToOtherTextLines(TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Here's your example working

[image]

And if you had an empty line, it is removed in the resulting string

[image]

Of course, you could overwrite the original textbox instead, but careful not to click the button twice!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = appendTextToOtherTextLines(TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Other option is an event handler which will make this happen automatically when pressing enter at the end of a new line. This is only useful if you are actively entering the lines manually.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.Length - 2) & TextBox2.Text & Environment.NewLine
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
    End If
End Sub
```

(this option requires some discipline when pressing enter)

Answer (score -2):

This is full working code.Enjoy it!!!!

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Me.TextBox1.Lines.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Please enter some data in textbox1")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        '---------------------------
        Dim b(Me.TextBox1.Lines.Length - 1) As String

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each a As String In Me.TextBox1.Lines
            b(i) = a + Me.TextBox2.Text
            i = i + 1
        Next
        '-----------------
        Me.TextBox1.Clear()
        Me.TextBox1.Lines = b
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain your code. By just dumping copy-pastable code the OP won't learn anything, and most likely neither will any future readers for that matter. Stack Overflow isn't meant to be a coding service. The goal is to actually _teach_ the question askers something.

Comment: Every thing in my answer is obvious and all codes are clear and my goal is to help people.I'm computer teacher in high school since 1999 So i know how to answer for best result !!!!

Comment: What is obvious to you might not be obvious to everyone. Seeing as the OP didn't manage to solve this on his own (and since he even explicitly stated in a comment that he is new to this) he might not understand it at all, let alone the other newcomers that find this question. Over the years here at SO I've come to learn that most newcomers infact does have a hard time understanding the concept of loops and arrays.

Comment: Why did you choose a For Each but then increment an integer.  Might as well use the For Loop enumerator instead.  You don't have to clear the box if you replace the Lines collection.

Comment: I didn't intend to be or sound mean in my comments, but when answering a question over the internet one loses important communication like body language and the tone variations in one's speech, making it harder for people to understand each other compared to when you speak face to face. Thus things one say on the internet is harder for others to understand and interpret. I was merely trying to help you help the OP even further, to ensure _he_ understands it.

Comment: No problem you can use For ... Each instead of for loop both are identical.