# Add text after every listbox line by line in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

im coding on vb.net (visual studio - basic)

i have a listbox and some lines with text of folder paths, when i press the first button to add in the end of the path "**:1**", and if ill press on the second button it will update to "**:2**", im looking to see this on the end of the text in every line each of them.

for example:

first button:

```
test1:1
test2:1
test3:1
test4:1
```

second button:

```
test1:2
test2:2
test3:2
test4:2
```

and it should be upading when pressing on the first button or the second one without duplicate the text or add over text, and keep all the lines on the same text just changing the last text with the "**:1**" or "**:2**".

Update:
im using with that code:

```
 For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        ListBox1.Items(i) += TextBox1.Text
    Next
```

but i want when press the button its not adding the string its just updating the last string at the line.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: im trying to do for example: drop a file and get all the path's of all the folders and files and after this i have button that i want when you press on it its write ":1" in every line at the end.

Comment: Does it have to be a listbox? [How to add text after every textbox line in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107666/how-to-add-text-after-every-textbox-line-in-vb-net).

Comment: yea im looking to work with the listbox

Comment: that link you post here i try this before, im looking for the same thing but when im pressing on button for example call one is updating all the lines in the end to ":1" and if im pressing on button call two its updating all of the lines in the end to ":2"

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim big As String = ""
For Each line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("r.txt")
Dim str As Integer = line.Split(":")(1)
big += line.Split(":")(0) & ":" & str + 1 & Environment.NewLine
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
Console.WriteLine(line.Split(":")(0) & ":" & str + 1)
Next
IO.File.WriteAllText("r.txt", big)
```

Comment: im using Listbox, i need it for listbox if you can convert this to listbox

Comment: @AnonyMM StackOverflow is not code writing service. You should be able to get generic ideas here and implement those yourselves.